# DFT equivalent circular convolution weight matrix with a symmetric filter of length 2K+1

Tags: dft, convolution

$\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}$In a research paper, I read that:

For optimization, the $n\times n$ weight matrix of DFT can be equivalent to circular convolution with a symmetric filter of length $2K+1$. That is the matrix rows are circularly shifted versions of $ h_{-K},...h_{-1},h_0,h_1,...h_K,0,...0)$.

PS: the DFT matrix is
$A = W^{-1}\diag(H_1,...,H_n)W$
, where $W$ is $n\times n$ DFT matrix, and $H_k=\frac{\alpha}{2}+j\frac{\beta}{2}(2\pi f_k)^2$

What exactly does this mean?  How can I get the expression of $h_K$?

Comment: i dunno what it means either.  may i suggest that you express every mathematical expression using $\LaTeX$?  they mixed HTML/LaTeX is a bit funky.

Comment: Hey, I must admit the "PS:" sounds a bit like a circular definition of the DFT matrix $A$ in terms of the DFT matrix $W$. I think I might be missing something!

Comment: Hi, I'm still confused about how the writer talks about optimizing × to 2+1 by circular convolution. Or step by step, what does it mean by this symmetric filter? I'm not quite sure that I understand the meaning of filter here. Thank you.

Comment: 2K+1 is probably less than N and it is zero-padded to N. Is this question in the context of OFDM systems?

Comment: Hi, thank you~ I guess you might get to the point but it is for optical communication. Just FYI the paper I read is arxiv.org/pdf/1710.06234.pdf